# accessing value of a variable which is located inside .on() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following method defined in the JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/g08mo4jw/). There are two JS files in the fiddle `f1.js` and `f2.js` respectively. I am testing to see if f2 can access the property from f1. Basically I want the value of `self.mySubtype` in `f2.js`. Defining a value `self.mySubtype = "Foo";` right outside the `.on()` method works fine and you will see `Foo`. However, when I tried to move the `self.mySubtype = "Foo";` inside the `.on()` method just below `self.mySubtype = obj.nc_subtype;` after commenting out `self.mySubtype = obj.nc_subtype;`, I get `undefined` message in `f2.js` alert.

Is there a way I can access this value, because in my web application code, I will need the value of `self.mySubtype` which is `obj.nc_subtype;` ?

```
$("#dataDocumentPanel").on('rowclick',function(event){

           var row = event.args.rowindex;

           var datarow = $("#dataDocumentPanel").jqxGrid('getrowdata', row);
           var jsonStringify = JSON.stringify(datarow,null,10);
           alert(jsonStringify); // This alert displays the JSON data in a formatted manner 
           var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
           //alert("display Subtype "+obj.nc_subtype)  // Works fine

           self.mySubtype = obj.nc_subtype;
           //self.mySubtype = "Foo"; // Doesn't works and displays undefined in f2 alert.

         });
```

Comment: If you eliminate the `var` before the declaration, the variable's scope becomes global. Would that be suitable for you? If yes, try it.

Comment: Hmm, if I have to first test the working of `self.mySubtype = "Foo";`, do I need to eliminate anything? Do you mean I should remove var from every variable inside `.on()` method?

Comment: When you declare a variable within a function with `var myVariable` you are actually confining the scope of the variable to the wrapping function. If you implicitly declare a variable without the `var` prefix, the variable's scope becomes global. So, you can try removing the `var` prefix from the variable you want to access and see what happens. That is essentially my suggestion.

Comment: One clarification: by GLOBAL I mean within the context of the environment where the function is being defined. This will not work if, for instance, you are invoking functions from different Angular Controllers (being a controller in fact a function with many internal functions).

Comment: So I am trying to access the value in another javascript file (`f2.js`) from `f1.js`. Both the files are in same folder and included in the HTML page. 
Here, what should be my approach since I believe the context of environment changes as soon as I try to access the variable from other file (`f2.js`)

Comment: The fact that you keep the two functions in separate files has no relevance at all since the browser loads all the files prior to start **making up its mind** about what to do. So, what I propose may or may not work, depending on the commonness of the context between the functions. Please just try it. It may do what you need.

Comment: I tried removing `var` from the line `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);` and the alert didn't work. The control isn't reaching `f2.js` for some reason I believe

Comment: Try swapping the order in which F1 and F2 are executed (since both have a `()`, they are auto-executed as soon as they are defined).

Comment: Not sure if I understood you when you said swapping F1 and F2,When the `.on()` method 
in `f1.js` executes then the `f2.js` alert is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.on('rowclick',function(event){` is not being ran.  The reason you can access the value when you put:

```
//I added this line for the demo to show 'f2' accessing this property from 'f1'. You should remove it if copying this code into your application
self.mySubtype = "Foo";
```

is because that code gets executed.  The on *rowclick* doesn't get executed unless that event happens.  It is not happening in your fiddle.  Once the row is **clicked** that code will get executed.

Comment: I have the code in my web app and onclick works but it doesn't shows anything in the alert of another page.